# Why Calendar broadcasts too many intents?

Tags: android, calendar, broadcastreceiver

I have registered BroadcastReceiver for Calendar Provider. Code works fine but when I just change one calendar event - I get several broadcasted intents. This would not be too much annoying but each intent in my app causes download all calendar events for specific time period. There could be lots of events in several days and each includes String texts and other data. Extra broadcasted intents force exchange too many extra data. And this all happens on mobile device connected to cellular or Wi-Fi network. This wastes traffic and battery.

I do not know - is there a way to separate really creative intent from others. Code is simple:

```java
class RegisterReceiver implements Runnable
{
    private Activity a;
    private CalendarReceiver receiver;
    public RegisterReceiver(Activity _a){
        a = _a;
    }

    public void run(){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED);
        filter.addDataScheme("content");
        filter.addDataAuthority("com.android.calendar", null);
        a.registerReceiver(receiver = new CalendarReceiver(), filter);
    }

    public CalendarReceiver getreceiver()
    {
        return receiver;
    }
}

class CalendarReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        MainControl.DebugMessage( intent.getAction() );
        MainControl.calendarChanged();
    }
}
```

The `MainControl.calendarChanged();` forces further processing. The `intent.getAction()` just contains info this is a "provider changed" intent. On each calendar action it appears several times with long delays. It is the same when I add calendar events, delete ot change them. Is there a way how to define which one intent is "my"? Is there any description of how to separate new, deleted, changed event intents?

Comment: That broadcast should not work on Android 9.0+ due to the ban on implicit broadcasts. Use a `ContentObserver`.

Comment: How? Where can I see examples of how use ContentObserver specially for Calendar?

Comment: From examples I see how to register ContentObserver for Calendar. I see how to be notified about Calendar changes. But I cannot find example how to extract detailed info about changed event or reminder. I need at least eventID of new, deleted or changed event. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok I changed notification to ContentObserver. It works much faster than BroadcastReceiver. But... When event created it again receives 3 notifications one by one with just "content://com.android.calendar" in Uri field.

Comment: "When event created it again receives 3 notifications one by one with just "content://com.android.calendar" in Uri field" -- the 3 notifications probably are due to the way the calendar data is being updated, and I doubt that you can do much about that. Ideally your observer would get a `Uri` pointing at the specific calendar entry that was changed, but that will depend a lot on the implementation of the `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Sometimes when event added - observer receives 2 notifications, sometimes 3. Not predictable. They come one by one almost immediately. Only 1 notification comes when event is deleted or changed. I have added observer for Reminders - but it receives notifications synchronously with Events observer. The Uri always is the same: "content://com.android.calendar". Now I have no idea how to properly synchronize my event tables when Android Calendar when it deletes event - there is no info which one event was deleted. There is not even info which one operation was done - deletion, editing or creation.